# How can i setup 2 nginx for same static dynamic content

Tags: nginx

I have a news site with lots of images and text. 
Is it possible to setup 2 nginx ,one for php-fpm and one for images css etc for the same site?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to divide static and dynamic content between two instances of e.g. `nginx`, one simple way to do this would be to have the second server instance on another (sub)domain.

So your primary server handing out web pages might live at `example.com`, while static content such as your images, JavaScript files and CSS might be delivered by a server that lives at `static.example.com`. You would then reference e.g. `static.example.com` in the web pages handed out by `example.com` whenever you needed to load those static items.